# Android FTP DownLoad Progressbar

Tags: java, android, ftp, android-asynctask

FTP code, but only the download...

```
public class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>{
String e;


protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
    String strResponce = "";
    ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    s="finish";
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER));
        ftpClient.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        textTargetUri.setText("good");


        final String remote = "/1.jpg";//FTP adress/filename
        String savefilepath = "/sdcard/download"+remote;
        File downloadfile = new File(savefilepath);//download

        local = new FileOutputStream(downloadfile);

        ftpClient.retrieveFile(remote, local);

        local.close();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

    }
    return s;
}
}
```

BUT!! FTP DownLoad code do insert `CountingOutputStream` function.
`CountingOutputStream` function is `commons-io-2.4.jar`.
project in `commons-io-2.4.jar` and `commons-net-3.3.jar` to there. T_T

```
public class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>{
String e;


protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
    String strResponce = "";
    ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    s="finish";
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER));
        ftpClient.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        textTargetUri.setText("good");

        final String remote = "/1.jpg";//FTP adress/filename
        String savefilepath = "/sdcard/download"+remote;
        File downloadfile = new File(savefilepath);//download

        local = new FileOutputStream(downloadfile);
        long fileSize = 0;
        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles(remote);
        if (files.length == 1 && files[0].isFile()) {
            fileSize = files[0].getSize();

            String a = String.valueOf(fileSize);
            Log.d("File Size", a);

        }

        CountingOutputStream cos = new CountingOutputStream(local) {
              protected void beforeWrite(int n) {
                      super.beforeWrite(n);

                      int progress = Math.round((getCount() * 100) / 879394);
                      //String b = String.valueOf(progress);
                      //Log.d("File persent", b);

              }
        };
        ftpClient.retrieveFile(remote, cos);

        local.close();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{

    }
    return s;
}


    }
```

What's wrong with the code, I do not know how?

code no error.

but APP start error.

Comment: `textTargetUri.setText("good");` not possible in `doInBackGround()`

Comment: textTargetUri.setText("good"); <<<delete

app start~ error.

What's wrong with the code, I do not know how?

Answer (score 0):

In a background tread (such as in `doInBackGround()`) no UI elements can be changed at all. If in activity use **runOnUiThread** or else use **textTargetUri.post**. This way the setText part takes place on the UI thread as needed.